# detect internet connection type in uwp allication?

Tags: javascript, windows, winjs, windows-10-universal, xbox-one

I am developing a uwp application that builds to windows store and xbox basically.

My code is like

```
var profile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
     var networkType=null;
     var interfaceType = profile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType;
        // 71 is WiFi & 6 is Ethernet
        if (interfaceType == 71) 
        {
          networkType="wifi";
        }

        else if (interfaceType == 6)
        {
          networkType="ethernet";
        }
```

when i was connected to wifi and run this code in xbox i am getting the connection type as "ethernet", but when i run the same code on my local machine i am getting the value as wifi.

Any helps appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the [`NetworkAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkadapter) class, if you check the device family of this class:

> Windows 10 (introduced v10.0.10240.0 - for Xbox, see UWP features that aren't yet supported on Xbox)

For Xbox, we need to check the  [UWP features not yet supported on Xbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/uwp-limitations-on-xbox), and `NetworkInformation`  is in "Feature areas less applicable to Xbox" section.

> NetworkUsage, ConnectivityInterval, NetworkInformation, and DataPlanStatus APIs are not supported on Xbox.

So it seems like it is currently not completely supported.